# How to set a color to a table cell in java

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I created a `JTable` and I want to set a color for a cell at run time. In this case I created a calendar using a table. I used default table model in this table for adding rows and columns.

How to color a cell in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by taking a look at [How to use tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), in particular, [Using Custom Renderers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer)

Basically, rendering of column is supplied through the use of a `TableCellRenderer`, this provides you the ability to make decisions about how a particular cell should be rendered at runtime.

`TableCellRenderer`'s are associated with a given `Class` type or table column